# includes with phppdf (ezPDF) on IIS

Tags: php, pdf, include

I'm using the ezPDF class, along with an added class for labels. They work great when my test file is in the same directory, but when I attempt to test with a file in another directory, all the text ends up on one line, overlapping.

I'm using php 5.05 on IIS (I know, I know). I've been researching and attempting stuff for a couple of hours, and am simply stuck. I'd prefer to get the includes working properly so I don't have to rely on the ini file.

Can anyone give me a hand on getting this to work?

Much appreciated.

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to different line endings in your test file and the real file. Test and real file edited with editors on different operation systems (Mac vs. Windows)?

Just checked the sources of ezPDF. Seems to split lines using \n. Thus \r would render different line to join.

Figure out, which file endings - \n \r - are in your test file and establish those in your real file.

More on line endings: [PHP Echo Line Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255511/php-echo-line-breaks)

Comment: Test file and real file are identical--only in separate directories. I gave in and simply put the class files in my root directory. Annoying.