# A break working on all platforms

Tags: php, windows, unix, break

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Echo Line Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255511/php-echo-line-breaks)

There is a `\n` for Windows and a `PHP_EOL` for UNIX (I *think*), but is there a break which works on every platform in a webapp? Or is the `PHP_EOL`-snippet the one I'm looking for?

Comment: The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform, is platform dependent value.

Comment: PHP_EOL doesn't "work on all platforms". it's simply the host platform's EOL character. If you generate a file on a Unix box using PHP_EOL, it won't magically start working on a Windows box, because on Unix, PHP_EOL is `\n`, and on Windows it's `\r\n`. It's simply a handle constant for you to use, so you don't have to figure out your host OS yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, `PHP_EOL` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

well, platforms has very little to do here.

The difference is only applicable to the text files, browsed in some outside program.

While for the output the rules may be different from these platform-related ones.
Say, for MIME and HTML "\r\n" is a standard despite of the platform

Answer (score 1):

`PHP_EOL` is platform-dependent, and will vary based on what OS PHP is running on.