# "\t" and <br> not working when I run my code

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
    echo "<h3>your order is processed !!!!</h3> <br>";
    $akash = $_POST["tires"];
    $akash2 = $_POST["Oil"];
    $akash3 = $_POST["plugs"];
    $akash4 = $_POST["hello"];
    $write = "tires is  ".$akash."<br>" ."Oil is " .$akash2."\t" ."Spark plug is " .$akash3."\t". "address is  " .$akash4."<br>";
    $open = fopen("order.txt","ab");
    $write = fwrite($open,$write);
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In what way are they not working? How are you displaying your resulting text file?

Comment: `\t` is not html, `<br/>` is html, if you open the file in browser you will get linebreaks, if you open it in notepad you propably get `tabs`. To linebrake in notepad you need `\n` or better use `\r\n`. Also, its not very important but..., you dont close the handle from `fopen`. And why are you overriding your string with the write-state ?

Comment: tires is  4<br>Oil is 2 litres Spark plug is 6 address is  adam@yahoo.com<br>This order was processed atSun Sep 2014              this is how my text file looks after i run my code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Carriage Return in PHP String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131619/create-carriage-return-in-php-string)

Answer (score 1):

Try  `/r/n` rather `<br>`(it's a html tag will not work with txt)

```
$write = "tires is  ".$akash."\r\n" ."Oil is " .$akash2."\t" ."Spark plug is " .$akash3."\t". "address is  " .$akash4."\r\n";
$open = fopen("order.txt","ab");
$write = fwrite($open,$write);
fclose($open);
```

in my case output is:-

```
tires is  sdff
Oil is ddddd    Spark plug is fffff address is  ggggg
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But what does \r\n mean

Comment: \r - carriage return , \n - newline you need to accept/upvote helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

you may want to drop the "b" in the fopen statement.
From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) , option b is "binary" which is probably causing the error.