# Explode every line from text file

Tags: php, arrays, file, text, explode

I am facing serious problem over some days. Trying to explode each line from **something.txt** file and make an array. But array structure not like what I want. My code is given below

```
    for ( $i=0; $i<count($_FILES['data']['name']['Question']['uploadfiles']); $i++) {
        foreach(file($_FILES['data']['name']['Question']['uploadfiles'][$i]) as $line) {
            $LineData[] = explode("\n",$line);
        }
    }
```

Some of the file lose the proper array structure. Just like

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [1] => 
    A. Hemophilia A
    B. Hemophilia B
                [2] => C. Von Willebrand disease
    D. Idiopathic thrombocytopenic purpura
            )
     )
```

But I want the array structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => A. Hemophilia A
            [2] => B. Hemophilia B
            [3] => C. Von Willebrand disease
            [4] => D. Idiopathic thrombocytopenic purpura
        )
 )
```

Comment: Could you give an excerpt of the file you are processing? Where is that file coming from, which OS are you using?

Comment: That txt file is created and saved using Mac OS

Answer (score 2):

Try using carriage return `"\r"` instead of line feed `"\n"`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131619/create-carriage-return-in-php-string) article, Mac is different from Windows and Linux in that respect.

Comment: Thanks Miqi180 for your answer. I have seen there is little improvement. This is nested array structure. But I do not want to see nested

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array (
                       [0] => A. Hemophilia A
                       [1] => B. Hemophilia B
                )
                
            )
     )

Comment: This is a long shot, but how about combining the two, i.e. "\n\r"?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your input file is not malformed/corrupt? And have you considered a string cleanup before the split?

Comment: Yes my file is not corrupted. And those code are using to split. No cleanup

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your file may still be malformed, even though it is not corrupted, and sometimes non-printable (invisible) characters tend to mess things up, so a cleanup may indeed be warranted after all.

Answer (score 1):

Save below on a `PHP` file and run in your local server and test

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $contents = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        $filearray = explode("\n", $contents);
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($filearray);
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="uploadForm">
        <input type="file" name="file"  />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SubirDas have you replaced the content.txt with your file name?

Comment: No I do not replace any file name

Answer (score 0):

The [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function already splits in lines. There is no reason to `explode` anything, unless you want to split **each line** separately.

In your case, the `file` call is sufficient, no need even for `foreach`:

```
$lineData = file($_FILES['data']['name']['Question']['uploadfiles'][$i]);
```

Comment: I am trying to split each line separately.

Comment: With what? You cannot split a line with a newline, because by definition, a line does not have a newline.