# How to add a line break in a string, this is some Drupal function

Tags: php, html, drupal

I want a line break in the #attributes, I've mentioned it in the code as in where I want the line break to be.

```
$form['advanced_user_data'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => array('"Jack Polard" <jackpolard@xyz.com> (Want a   line break here) "Miky Town" <miky@abc.com> (Want a line break here) "Bill Gates" <bill@example.com>')),
    '#description' => t('Eg: "Full Name" &nbsp;&nbsp; < emailid@domain.com >'),                                                       
);
```

See this is how it has to be, "\r\n" didnt work, I'm a HTML guy, so I have no knowledge of PHP, please help me in a simpler way.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Echo Line Breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255511/php-echo-line-breaks)

Comment: i clicked that next button but it was image :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your linebreaks should used in a `textarea` use `&#10;` this is command for newlines in html. give this a try.

// edit after comment

try

```
'#attributes' => array('placeholder' => array('"Jack Polard" <jackpolard@xyz.com>
                                                "Miky Town" <miky@abc.com>
                                                "Bill Gates" <bill@example.com>')),
```

if this and the other solutions ... `\n` etc... not work, i think the output to your `textarea` gets  `htmlescaped`, so you can't use linebreaks as long the complete output gets escaped.

Comment: I can give spaces, I've tried, but the textarea is responsive, then the words break when resized.

Comment: then i think you need to correct the output and remove the ``htmlescape`` from the ``textarea``

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time `\n` or `\r\n` or `PHP_EOL` will do the trick. Just try which one works for you. If you echo to html you should use `<br>`.

Comment: not my downvote but better to use ``PHP_EOL`` in php

Comment: Edited it to complete the answer for future reference.

Comment: It does work when saving text files. I don't know the context in which you are using this.