# php while line jump with xml

Tags: php, xml

i want to create xml file with php ...

How can I jump line? with br or  \ n?

I try it every time.

can anyone help me?

```
include "ayar.php";
$myFile = "rss.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");



$rss_txt .= '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
$rss_txt .= '<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">';
$rss_txt .= '<channel>';

 while($values_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
 {
        $rss_txt .= '<item>';
        $rss_txt .= '<g:title>' .$values_query['baslik']. '</g:title><br />';
        $rss_txt .= '<g:description>' .$values_query['aciklama']. '</g:description><br />';
        $rss_txt .= '<g:link>' .$values_query['resim1k']. '</g:link><br />';
        $rss_txt .= '<g:image_link>' .$values_query['resim1k']. '</g:image_link><br />';    
        $rss_txt .= '</item>';

 }
$rss_txt .= '</channel>';
$rss_txt .= '</rss>';

fwrite($fh, $rss_txt);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Have a quick read about [double-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RockwoodON did state correctly, a `<br />` is not the way to go here. `<br />` is a tag for HTML renderers to render a newline. To format your XML you will need line break characters/strings, which are unfortunately not platform independent.

[Every platform has its line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255512/2249175)

- Windows hat Carriage Return plus linefeed (`"\r\n"`)
- *nix (excluding macOS) has a single linefeed `"\n"`
- macOS has a single carriage return `"\r"`

Having said that, most modern editors might recognize several/all of those options. notepad++ does, VS too, just to mention two. So the choice of line breaks should depend on your target system/editor or use-case respectively.

If the system your code runs on is the same as the target platform, you might use `PHP_EOL` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255531/2249175)), but it's only useful as long as you are not switching platforms on either side. **But** you should really think about defining you own constant, to stay consistent withing your file

```
define('EOL',   '\r\n');

// ...

$rss_txt .= '<item>';
$rss_txt .= '<g:title>' .$values_query['baslik']. '</g:title>'.EOL;
$rss_txt .= '<g:description>' .$values_query['aciklama']. '</g:description>'.EOL;
$rss_txt .= '<g:link>' .$values_query['resim1k']. '</g:link>'.EOL;
$rss_txt .= '<g:image_link>' .$values_query['resim1k']. '</g:image_link>'.EOL;    
$rss_txt .= '</item>';
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTML line break sequence is definitely not right. I believe you need to use a 'carriage return' (CR) which could be written in your string as \r